# Css class changing immediately instead of using transition

Tags: html, css, angular, css-transitions

I've got a page-loading component.
There should be only white screen for some time, then the loading image + message should appear.
But it doesn't work and loader appears immediately. What is wrong?

html

```
    <div class="full-screen-centered-layout" >
    <div id="loader">        
        <img class="loading-image" src=[Loader image] />
        <h3  *ngIf="PageLoadingMessage" class="loading-message">{{ PageLoadingMessage | translate }}...</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.full-screen-centered-layout {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: grid;
    z-index: 2;
}

.loading-image {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
}

.loading-message {
    text-align: center;
    color: lightgray;
}

#loader {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    opacity: 0;
}

#loader.show {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Part of the component where I am changing classes

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Initialize();
}

private Initialize(): void{
    let element = document.getElementById("loader");
    element .classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. change the loader to class instead of id. as id is more specific the .show class added will not make it.

```
  <div class="loader">
        <img class="loading-image" src="./logo.jpg" />
        <h3 *ngIf="PageLoadingMessage" class="loading-message">{{ 
         PageLoadingMessage | translate }}...</h3>
  </div>
```

```
.loader {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    transition: opacity 2s linear 2s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

2. on the class .show give the transition-duration(times in seconds) and the property
   that needs to be affected

```
.show {
    transition-duration: 5s;
    transition-property: opacity;
}
```